# Text-align child elements not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a one-on-one chat and I want the messages to be in bubbles form.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="msgWindow" class="block">
    <div id="messages">
    <p class="sysmsg">You're now connected with a random chat partner...</p>
    <p class="sysmsg">Say Hello!</p><p class="msg-item">
    <span class="stranger">Stranger</span> hey</p>
    <p class="msg-item"><span class="you">Me</span> hi</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image]

So what I basically want to do is to `text-align` the first message to the right and to keep the second one on the left.

I tried with this CSS but it's not working ..

```
#messages{
    height: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#messages p{
    padding: 5px 0;
    }
.msg-item{
}
.you, .stranger{
    padding: 4px;
    color: #FFF4F4;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.you{    
    background-color: #555;
    text-align: right;

}
.stranger{    
    background-color: #D94D58;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ap06vku7/

Comment: Or this? https://jsfiddle.net/17tfxm1w/1/

Comment: @h_h10a did you check the answer?

Comment: @Dekel, Yes, thank you all !

Comment: It the answer is correct please accept & vote it :) thanks!

Comment: @Dekel Already did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text-align` should be on the container (the block element that wrap your text).

Here is an example for a fix:

```css
#messages{
  height: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#messages p{
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.msg-item{
}
.you span, .stranger span{
  padding: 4px;
  color: #FFF4F4;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.you span{    
  background-color: #555;

}
.stranger span{    
  background-color: #D94D58; 
}
p.you {
  text-align: right;
}
p.stranger {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="msgWindow" class="block">
  <div id="messages">
    <p class="sysmsg">You're now connected with a random chat partner...</p>
    <p class="sysmsg">Say Hello!</p>
    <p class="msg-item stranger"><span>Stranger</span> hey</p>
    <p class="msg-item you"><span>Me</span> hi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```